# One time login with twitter using STTwitterAPI

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, semaphore, sttwitter

How can i check user is already login with twitter or not by using its authToken and authTokenSecret?

I am using this code but its return value without wait for completing the block execution. How to use semaphore or something else to wait until block execute then function return its value.

```
- (BOOL)isTwitterLogin
{
  __block BOOL value;


    NSString *oauthToken=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"iNtellTwitterToken"];
    NSString *oauthTokenSecret=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"iNtellTwitterTokenSecret"];


    STTwitterAPI *twitterAPI = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:kTwitterConsumerKey consumerSecret:kTwitterConsumerSecret oauthToken:oauthToken oauthTokenSecret:oauthTokenSecret];

    [twitterAPI verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username)
     {
         /// we still good to go
         value=1;
     } errorBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {
         /// token has expired. User needs to login again
         value=0;
     }];
    return value;
}
```

i am looking for best way to execute this method..

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best way" would probably keep the asynchronous behaviour:

```
- (void)isTwitterLoginWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(BOOL isTwitterLogin))completionHandler {

    NSString *oauthToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"iNtellTwitterToken"];
    NSString *oauthTokenSecret = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"iNtellTwitterTokenSecret"];

    if(oauthToken == nil || oauthTokenSecret == nil) {
        completionHandler(NO);
        return;
    }

    STTwitterAPI *twitterAPI = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:@""
                                                             consumerSecret:@""
                                                                 oauthToken:oauthToken
                                                           oauthTokenSecret:oauthTokenSecret];

    [twitterAPI verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {
        completionHandler(YES);
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        completionHandler(NO);
    }];
}
```

Comment: How to call this function in if block? like if(isTwitterLoginWithCompletionHandler){ }

Comment: [self isTwitterLoginWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL isTwitterLogin) { /*...*/ }]; the completion handler may be called asynchronously.